# What is the difference in meaning between "piqué", "relevé" and "assaisonné"?

Tags: verbes, synonymes

> « Les concombres épicés ont été **piqués** de gousses d'ail. »
>
> My translation: *The spiced cucumbers have been **made even more spicy** with cloves of garlic.*

I don’t understand how "piquer" is different in meaning from "relever" or "assaisonner". These three verbs seem so similar and confusing to me.

> « Les concombres épicés ont été **relevés** de gousses d'ail. »
>
> « Les concombres épicés ont été **assaisonnés** de gousses d'ail. »

Comment: With cucumbers and other veggies your translation of  “piqués de gousses d'ail” may very well be correct, but when meat is involved (especially lamb), I’ve always interpreted “piqués a l'ail” to mean literally to be “pierced/implanted with garlic cloves,” as is being done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdNX3wryyEo) to  what appears to be a chicken breast. Of course, this is done to season the meat/give it a taste/hint of garlic, but I don’t think, with meat at least, that “piqué” means to season or give a spicy taste to [the meat].

Comment: « piqué » is not spicy, « piquant » is spicy (at least in foods). Talking about foods, « piqué »  sense is from its literal meaning, with "spikes/stings".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

Conclusion part:

> While *assaisonner* or *relever* characterize **how you are seasonning** your meal, *piquer* some piece of food with another is a **culinary technique to season** a meal.

### Piqué

#### Short, meaning

As @PapaPoule comment said, *"piqué"* is used to talk about some piece of food which has been pricked with another, or with some spice, which have been leaved inside, to add taste during cooking.

---

#### Dictionary

The [13th meaning of piquer](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/piquer) from wiktionary is accurate :

> 13. Larder.
>
>     > *Piquer de gros lard un morceau de bœuf, Le larder avec de gros lardons.*

The etymology of this meaning seems to first involve meat but now it can be approximately used with any piece of food.

---

#### pics or it didn't happen

You can find recipes using this technique :

- *"[Pot au feu](http://cecilemillot.canalblog.com/archives/2009/10/24/15554109.html)"* with *"1 oignon piqué de clous de girofle"*
  [image: oignon]
- *"[Roti de boeuf](http://www.cuisinenligne.com/public/images/recettes/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure/medium/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure-0.jpg) à l'ail par Laure"*
  [roti http://www.cuisinenligne.com/public/images/recettes/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure/medium/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure-0.jpg](http://www.cuisinenligne.com/public/images/recettes/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure/medium/roti-de-boeuf-a-l-ail-par-laure-0.jpg)

---

### Other

#### assaisonné

It is adding spices with no particular connotation, it can be soft or hot.

[Wiktionary meaning](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/assaisonner) :

> Accommoder un mets avec les ingrédients qu’il faut pour le rendre plus agréable au goût.

---

#### relevé

It is adding spices but, this time, to make it hot[ter].

[17th wiktionary meaning](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/relever) :

> 17. (Cuisine) Donner un goût plus piquant, un plus haut goût à des assaisonnements, à des sauces, à des ragoûts.

---

#### Conclusion

While *assaisonner* or *relever* characterize **how you are seasonning** your meal, *piquer* some piece of food with another is a **culinary technique to season** a meal.

Answer (score 2):

Your translation is not correct. At least french natives will not interpret it like that. *Piqués de gousses d'ail* is a common term in culinary recipes to say implanted with garlic cloves.

On the other side *assaisonner* indeed means *to season* or *to dress* when speaking of a meal or a salad. *Relevé* in culinary terms is closer to hot, while *épicé* is spicy.